# jquery (getJSON) called after enclosing function of enclosing function exits

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am calling some jquery in a function via another function which is itself called at button press time.  It turns out that the jquery request to the server is not executed until the original calling function exits.  The effect is that the button which is added is ultimately deleted by code which I expected to run before the button is added (that code contains an empty() command).  Please have a look. What is happening here?

```
function get_user_from_database() {
  var user_name_search_string = $("#user_name_search_string").val();
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/get_user_for_admin_purposes', {
    user_name_search_string: user_name_search_string
  }, function(data) {
    var userNode = $("#list_of_users");
    userNode.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
      var cb = document.createElement("input");
      cb.type = "radio";
      cb.value = data.users[i].user_ID;
      cb.checked = false;
      cb.name = "selected_user";
      userNode[0].appendChild(cb);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode(data.users[i].user_name);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var br = document.createElement("br");
      userNode[0].appendChild(br);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode("Date joined : " + data.users[i].date_joined);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var br = document.createElement("br");
      userNode[0].appendChild(br);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode("User Role : " + data.users[i].role);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var br = document.createElement("br");
      userNode[0].appendChild(br);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode("User Email : " + data.users[i].email);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      userNode[0].appendChild(p);
    }
  });
}


$(function() {
  $('#user_name_search_button_assign_moderator').on('click', function(e) {
    get_user_from_database();
    var userNode = $("#list_of_users");
    var aButton = document.createElement("input");
    aButton.type = "submit";
    aButton.value = "Assign Moderator Status";
    aButton.id = "assign_mod_status_button"
    userNode[0].appendChild(aButton);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I should have googled a bit first.  I now know that getJSON is non blocking and so the rest of the code executes.  How should I organize this code so that I can call the server and, only upon success of server call, do some more code?

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_user_from_database(callback) {
  var user_name_search_string = $("#user_name_search_string").val();
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/get_user_for_admin_purposes', {
    user_name_search_string: user_name_search_string
  }, function(data) {
    var userNode = $("#list_of_users");
    userNode.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
      var cb = document.createElement("input");
      cb.type = "radio";
      cb.value = data.users[i].user_ID;
      cb.checked = false;
      cb.name = "selected_user";
      userNode[0].appendChild(cb);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode(data.users[i].user_name);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var br = document.createElement("br");
      userNode[0].appendChild(br);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode("Date joined : " + data.users[i].date_joined);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var br = document.createElement("br");
      userNode[0].appendChild(br);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode("User Role : " + data.users[i].role);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var br = document.createElement("br");
      userNode[0].appendChild(br);
      var theTxt = document.createTextNode("User Email : " + data.users[i].email);
      userNode[0].appendChild(theTxt);
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      userNode[0].appendChild(p);
    }

    callback();
  });
}


$(function() {
  $('#user_name_search_button_assign_moderator').on('click', function(e) {
    get_user_from_database(function() {
      var userNode = $("#list_of_users");
      var aButton = document.createElement("input");
      aButton.type = "submit";
      aButton.value = "Assign Moderator Status";
      aButton.id = "assign_mod_status_button"
      userNode[0].appendChild(aButton);
    });
  });
});
```